# Programmed a method to create a PDF and another to create an excel. They both download files on local but won't work in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, jspdf

I'm trying to create a pfd and excel files with details of orders. Files will download into my directory when the functions are triggered in local but won't download when triggered in production (in the web). How can I make the functions download files into the client's computer when in the web? At what point is it not downloading in the web?

Here's the code:

```
module.exports.createPDF = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
      const id = req.body.id
      const doc = new jsPDF({
          orientation: 'p',
          unit: 'mm',
          format: 'a4'
      });
      var txtFormat = ''
      var recipt_name = ''
      for (let id_num of id) {

          const order = await Order.findById(id_num).populate('customer')
          txtFormat += `Articulo: ${order.name} -- Precio: ${order.price} -- Nombre: ${order.customer.username}\nAsiento: ${order.seat}${order.letter} -- Seccion: ${order.section}\
      \n*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*\n`
          recipt_name += order.name, ","
      }
      doc.text(txtFormat, 20, 20)
      const date = new Date();
      month = date.getMonth() + 1
      day = date.getDate()
      year = date.getFullYear()

      file_num = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
      doc.save(`${day}_${month}_${year}--${file_num}.pdf`)
      res.redirect('/places')

  } catch (e) {
      req.flash('Refresca la Pagina e Intenta de Nuevo')
      res.redirect('/places')
  }
}

module.exports.createReport = async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

      const id = req.body.id
      var all_orders = []
      for (let id_num of id) {
          const order = await Order.findById(id_num)
          const new_order = { price: order.price, articulo: order.name, date: order.date, section: order.section }
          all_orders.push(new_order)
          order.is_reported = false
          order.save()
      }

      const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(all_orders);
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, "orders")
      // Generate buffer
      XLSX.write(workBook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: "buffer" })

      // Binary string
      XLSX.write(workBook, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "binary" })
      const date = new Date();
      month = date.getMonth() + 1
      day = date.getDate()
      year = date.getFullYear()

      file_num = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
      XLSX.writeFile(workBook, `${day}_${month}_${year}--${file_num}.xlsx`)

      res.redirect('/places')

  } catch (e) {
      req.flash('Refresca la Pagina e Intenta de Nuevo')
      res.redirect('/places')
  }
}
```

Comment: You're saving the file into whatever happens to be the working directory on the production server. That won't help with getting them down the wire to your client.

Comment: I'm also _positive_ that this code doesn't "download into your directory" – yes, it will write into a directory on your machine, but that has nothing to do with _downloading_ which is done by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your method downloads the file in the Server machine not the Client's,

JavaScript is a secure language, so downloading a file to the client isn't as easy as some other languages, but there is a hack for this:

you can add a hidden iframe to your HTML structure:

```html
<iframe id="myiframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

then create a `download` function that you will call passing it the URL of the file each time you want to dowload the file in the client's machine:

```js
const download = (URL) => {
    document.getElementById('myiframe').src = URL;
};
```

Then you can delete the file from the server if you want to, adjust this example to make it work in your project.

Comment: How would OP know what `URL` is here?

Comment: @AKX, He does save the file using `doc.save()` or `XLSX.writeFile()`, these create the file in the server, he can call the download function i provided in the end of his functions using his upload url plus the name of the file he created, for example in his `createReport` function he could use something like _**download(`uploads/${day}_${month}_${year}--${file_num}.xlsx`)**_ to download the created file.

Comment: Yes, _if_ they have even set up the directory where those files are written to be served by the server. That's my point here.

Comment: Yes true, even tho they will be written eitherways to the server, using the uploads/ folder for example is just for best practices, but you got what I mean